# Slicing the list in prolog between two indexes

Tags: list, prolog, slice

I'm trying to slice a list, and create a result list that contains elements that fall between two indices, exclusive.

```
indexOf([Element|_], Element, 0). % We found the element
indexOf([_|Tail], Element, Index):-
  indexOf(Tail, Element, Index1), % Check in the tail of the list
  Index is Index1+1.  % and increment the resulting index

less_than(0, 0).
less_than(X, N) :-
    X < N.
    
greater_than(0, 0).
greater_than(X, N) :-
    X > N.

slice([], 0, 0, []).
slice([H|T], I, N, R) :-
    indexOf([H, T], H, Ind), % get the index of the H
    (less_than(Ind, N),
    greater_than(Ind, I), % check if that index is between I and N
    slice(T, I, N, H|R);  % if it is - call the slice again, but append the H to the result
    slice(T, I, N, R)).   % if it's not, just call the slice regularly with the rest of the items
```

For instance, `slice([a,b,c,d], 0, 4, R)` R should be [b,c].

Now this always fails but I'm not sure why.
Is it the base case, or is is the 'if-else' statement between the parenthesis?
I would like to accomplish this without using build-in predicates.

Comment: When I try to run this code Prolog only tells me that "indexOf/3 does not exist". How is it supposed to work?

Comment: What does it mean, "between two indices, exclusive". What should happen with `slice([a,b,c,d], 1, 2, Slice)`?

Comment: sorry, forgot to add that part.

Comment: slice([a,b,c,d], 1, 2, Slice) should return the empty list.
slice([a,b,c,d], 0, 4, Slice) should return [b,c].

Comment: `H|R` is not list syntax. You probably meant `[H|R]`.

Answer (score 2):

There are some fundamental flaws in your algorithm. You seem to be processing one item at a time but didn't take into account that your input list keeps shrinking, so you should decrement your starting index by one each time. Your base case probably should not check that the ending index be 0, you never modify it and you wouldn't call it with 0.

Also your `indexOf/3` procedure seems to find any location where the item is found (there may be duplicate items in your list).

You are also misusing the list structure `[Head|Tail]` (forgot the square brackets).

You may do your slicing by using [`append/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3):

```
slice(L, From, To, R):-
  length(LFrom, From),
  length([_|LTo], To),
  append(LTo, _, L),
  append(LFrom, R, LTo).
```

In this answer I assumed your index starts at 1.

Sample run:

```
?- slice([a,b,c,d,e], 1, 4, R).
R = [b, c].
```